# How to speedup by code?

Tags: php, performance, cycle

is there a way to speed up my code? It takes about 15 seconds to load ... I don't really see a way to reduce my code... I just thought about inserting the values into database, so the user does not have to load new info every time.. but the thing is that my cron only allows 1 load per hour ... by loading new info on every load it gives me fresh information..

```
$q1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM isara");

while($r1=mysql_fetch_array($q1)){

        $named=$r1['name'];
        $idd=$r1['id'];
        $descd=$r1['desc'];
        $online=check_online($named);

        $char = new Character($r1['name'],$r1['id'],$r1['desc']);

        if($online == "online"){
                $char->rank = $i++;    
        }
        else{
                $char->rank = 0;
        }

        $arr[] = $char;

}
?>

<br />
<h2 style="color:green">Online enemies</h2>

<?php
foreach ($arr as $char) {
        if($char->rank>=1){
                echo "<a style=\"color:green\" href=\"http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=$char->name\">";
                echo $char->name." ";
                echo "</a>";
                echo level($char->name)."<b> ";
                echo vocation($char->name)."</b> (<i>";
                echo $char->desc." </i>)<br />";
        }
}
?>
<br /> 
<h2 style="color:red">Offline enemies</h2>
<?php
foreach ($arr as $char) {
        if($char->rank==0){
                echo "<a style=\"color:red\" href=\"http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=$char->name\">";
                echo $char->name." ";
                echo "</a>";
                echo level($char->name)."<b> ";
                echo vocation($char->name)."</b> (<i>";
                echo $char->desc." </i>)<br />";
        }
}

?>
```

Comment: How does the `check_online` method look like?

Comment: `function check_online($name){
$count=substr_count($name, " ");
if($count > 0){
$ex=explode(" ",$name);
$namez=$ex[1];
$nameused=$namez;
}
else{
$nameused=$name;
}
$content=file_get_contents("http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&world=Isara",0);
if(preg_match("/$nameused/",$content)){
$status="online";
}
else{
$status="offline";
}
return $status;
}`

Comment: Right, so you are fetching the exact same page for every name in your database? Fetch once, check against it many times.

Comment: Will do! I feel stupid! Thanks!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comment, fetch the page once instead of once for every name in the database.

Pseudo code for my comment:

```
users = <get users from database>
webpage = <get webpage contents>

for (user in users)
    <check if user exists in webpage>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you're calling a webpage for each entry in your database, assuming that's about 2 seconds per call it's going to slow you down a lot.

Why don't you call the page once and pass the contents of it into the check_online() function as a parameter so your code would look something like this which will speed it up by quite a few magnitudes:

```
$content=file_get_contents("http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=worlds&worl‌​d=Isara",0);
$q1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM isara");

while($r1=mysql_fetch_array($q1)){

    $named=$r1['name'];
    $idd=$r1['id'];
    $descd=$r1['desc'];
    $online=check_online($named,$content);

    $char = new Character($r1['name'],$r1['id'],$r1['desc']);

    if($online == "online"){
            $char->rank = $i++;    
    }
    else{
            $char->rank = 0;
    }

    $arr[] = $char;

}
?>

<br />
<h2 style="color:green">Online enemies</h2>

<?php
foreach ($arr as $char) {
    if($char->rank>=1){
            echo "<a style=\"color:green\" href=\"http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=$char->name\">";
            echo $char->name." ";
            echo "</a>";
            echo level($char->name)."<b> ";
            echo vocation($char->name)."</b> (<i>";
            echo $char->desc." </i>)<br />";
    }
}
?>
<br /> 
<h2 style="color:red">Offline enemies</h2>
<?php
foreach ($arr as $char) {
    if($char->rank==0){
            echo "<a style=\"color:red\" href=\"http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=$char->name\">";
            echo $char->name." ";
            echo "</a>";
            echo level($char->name)."<b> ";
            echo vocation($char->name)."</b> (<i>";
            echo $char->desc." </i>)<br />";
    }
}

?>
```

and your check_online() function would look something like this:

```
function check_online($name,$content){
    $count=substr_count($name, " "); 
    if($count > 0){ $ex=explode(" ",$name); $namez=$ex[1]; $nameused=$namez; } 
    else{ $nameused=$name; } 
    if(preg_match("/$nameused/",$content)){ $status="online"; } 
    else{ $status="offline"; }     
    return $status; 
}
```

You can also do the following to make it faster

1. Stop using select * which is very bad on innodb
2. Put better indexes on your database to make the recordset return faster
3. Install PHP 5.4 as it's faster especially as you're creating a new object in each iteration
4. Use a byte code accelerator/cache such as xdebug

Answer (score 0):

you should avoid using distinct (*) keyword in your SQL Query
for more information read this http://blog.sqlauthority.com/category/sql-coding-standards/page/2/